# Connecting Graphql to Symfony Templates

Tags: php, symfony, graphql

I am starting to work on Graphql integration into Symfony. I have a github repo https://github.com/overblog/GraphQLBundleDemo up and running. I understand the concepts of what is happening within the resolvers, but I can't find any help or documentation about how I would go about connecting this to a front end application or create an end point to push ajax queries through. The map() function in MyresolverMap.php does not allow for any parameters to pushed to the function.

If anyone has any experience or examples to point me to that would be very helpful.

Comment: Do you know that [API Platform has GraphQL support](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/graphql/)?

Comment: Thanks Chris, yeah I have seen the platform, but at this stage I am trying to get a platform set up from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I managed to realise that I just need to create an endpoint and connect the twig template directly to endpoint using ajax, in the same way I would for rest API's. I am using the GraphQL Bundle for Symfony and I updated the endpoint by changing the config/routes/graphql.yaml file to the following:

```
overblog_graphql_endpoint:
    resource: "@OverblogGraphQLBundle/Resources/config/routing/graphql.yml"
    prefix: /graphdata
```

I am still learning, so go easy on me.